# Npm run build is only working on index.html and not my other two pages

Tags: npm, build, vite, netlify

so I am trying to deploy my first site to Netlify. I have a simple three page static site using html/css (tailwind, alpine.js)

The site is working just fine on the index page, but not the other two: https://main--magenta-custard-d7d779.netlify.app/

In the asset folder index-f03ee9b6.css is added and the route is changed on the index.html.
If I move the about.html, contact.html into the 'public' folder, they are added to the dist but are not amended in any way, so when set live, you can move to through the pages, but no styles are applied.

If anyone has any idea why this build is failing I would really appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: By adding the following code, i resolved the build:

// vite.config.js
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        contact: resolve(__dirname, 'contact.html'),
        about: resolve(__dirname, 'about.html'),
      },
    },
  },
});